# Adding HTML,CSS and Javascript to Joomla frontpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla, joomla2.5

I need to insert a **custom search box** in the middle of joomla frontpage.
The *searchbox* would contain html, css and java script.I tried using `mod html` and `moduleanywhere`. still no luck.

I would appreciate if any pros out there could advise me on this.

Comment: do you already have a search module that you have downloaded?

Comment: I use a module called "Jrool" that lets me include custom PHP code into my Joomla articles. This plugin however seems to be dead and is hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules/16359

If that one doesn't work for you, there are a whole bunch of modules that do basically the same thing here - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules

As a last resort (actually this is the best way to do it) you can also create a custom module for your search box. It's really not that hard to do and it's much better to do it this way since you are not using an extension to add more code.

You can get info on module dev here - http://docs.joomla.org/Module_Development
And here is a quick video tutorial to get you started - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qd93be8YRNY